# combo box index gets [object Object] instead of number in extjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs

I have and extjs task running in Ext.TaskManager which reloads my ext store every 5 seconds. Each time the task is called I update currentIndex variable that holds the currently selected index(value) in my combobox. The probelm i get is that in some circumstances instead of getting number currentIndex gets value [object Object]. I really have no idea why this happens. Here is my sample code:

```
// combo store
var myStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    id: store_id,
    fields: ['label', 'value', 'type'],
    autoLoad: true,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: '/url/to/controller',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'MyModel'
        }
    }
}),

 createWindow = function() {
    var myComboBox = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.ComboBox', {
        flex: 3,
        editable: false,
        value: 'Select option',
        displayField: 'label',
        valueField: 'value',
        store: myStore,
        cls: 'comboCssClass',
        id: ComboBoxId,
        listeners: {
            'select': function(combo, row, index) {
                var rowData = row[0].data;
                currentIndex = this.getValue();
             }
        }
   };

   return newWindow = Ext.create('Ext.widget.window',{
          // window settings
          items:[myComboBox ]
   });
},

reloadStoretask = {
    run: function(){
          myStore.load();

          // here is where in some cases I get [object Object] instead of number 
          // And I think the object is Ext.data.store.ImplicitModel or it was alike. 
          // so currentIndex = [object Object] in some cases
          record = myStore.getAt(currentIndex).data;
    },
    interval: 5000
}
```

How to fix this or what do i do wrong?

Comment: Where are you calling myComboBox to run?

Comment: Well unfortunatelly it is created in a separate function that creates extjs window. See updated code

Comment: What is the data that is being used to populate the store when the error occurs?

Comment: Auu I think I erased 'MyModel' i.ethere is no MyModel. Could this be the problem?

Comment: Hmmm still not swing where you call combobox... You include it in items array, is there something that calls functions on the list? And yes it looks like myModel is nowhere to be found.

Comment: I create combo as part of widget window. The widget window is created when I press menu item like this createWindow().show(). Ok?

Comment: Well I added XTemplate to it and I still dont know how to make it work :) Could this be the problem?

Comment: Show us your data that is returned from server. You defined `root` property as `MyModel`. Are you sure that data has correct format like `{ MyModel: [{label: 'label1', value: 'value1', type: 'type1'}, {...}] }`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be you are loading your store twice, you configured your store with autoload:true then you call reloadStoretask function to reload the store.